# Scala Actors Send Message to Super Class

Tags: scala, actor

I'm trying to make a base class that uses actors, kind of like so:

```
import scala.actors.Actor


case class FooBar()


class ParentActor extends Actor {



def act {

  loop {

    react {

      case  f: FooBar =>

        println("Parent Foo")

      case _ =>

        println("Parent something")

    }

  }

}

}
```

And then I want a child class to look like so:

```
class ChildActor extends ParentActor {

  override def act {

    loop {

      react {

        case i: Integer =>

          println("Child int")

        case default =>

          println("Child Base")
          super ! default


      }

    }


  }


}
```

My end goal is to provide a base functionality in the parent actor class that will be executed if the child actor does not react to that case class. I tried doing

```
super ! Message
```

But that throws an error:

> '.' expected but identifier found.

How can I pass a message from the ChildActor to the base ParentActor act function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code which processes the received messages is the [PartialFunction](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html) which is passed to the `react` method - in other words it's that case block/closure. It's not possible to call directly any closures which are declared inside other methods (including the superclass' methods), unless that method somehow passes you a reference to the closure instance. And anyways code reuse through inheritance should be avoided.

Since a case block is a [PartialFunction](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/PartialFunction.html), it's possible to compose multiple such blocks using the `orElse` method. That way you can combine multiple case blocks so that it will fall back to the next one if there is no match for a message.

You don't need inheritance to compose the handlers - just expose the "parent handler" somewhere as a function and compose them before calling `react`. Or to reduce the boilerplate and make ChildActor unaware of the code in the parent, override the `react` method in the ParentActor and do the composing of the handlers there before passing it to `super.react`.